# Search domains in Debian 8 with systemd-resolved

Tags: dhcp, linux-networking, systemd

I'm running Debian 8 + systemd215. I'm trying to setup domain suffix to be appended automatically, when I ping other hosts in LAN. Before systemd I'd just add below line to:

`#/etc/resolv.conf
search sub2.sub1.mydomain`

But now on modern system `resolve.conf` is linked to `/var/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`. So added below lines:

`#/etc/systemd/network/eth.network
[DHCP]
UseDomains=true
#/etc/systemd/resolved.conf
[Resolve]
Domains=sub2.sub1.mydomain`

Restart networkd/resolved and got below messages in journal:

`systemd-networkd[15171]: [/etc/systemd/network/eth.network:9] Unknown lvalue 'UseDomains' in section 'DHCP'
...
systemd-resolved[16332]: [/etc/systemd/resolved.conf:12] Unknown lvalue 'Domains' in section 'Resolve'`

I found, this might be actually a bug in systemd prior to 228. I do not see any fresh versions of systemd available for my Debian from stable repo. So should I just go and unlink `/etc/resolve.conf` and add searched domains in old fashioned way? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Serverfault.

The list of all directives available in your currently installed version of `systemd` is available in `man systemd.directives`. Search in that document to see if "Domains" is available in your version.

If the directives you need are not available, then, yes, you should use the traditional resolver instead of the `systemd` resolver.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mark. This ``man systemd.directives`` is rather useful.